# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "sinnfrei" und "sinnlos"?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-usage

Der Duden definiert "sinnfrei" als "völlig ohne Sinn" und "sinnlos" als "ohne Vernunft, ohne erkennbaren Sinn". Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Wörtern?

Comment: Wer benutzt "sinnfrei" wirklich? Ich hab das Wort noch nie benutzt.

Comment: "Sinnfrei" ist bis jetzt nur ein (hässliches) Modewort.

Comment: Es ist zwar oft völlig *sinnfrei*, aber man benutzt es gerne. Ich habs schon oft gehört und benutzt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sinnfrei: sind die Posts der anderen Diskussionsteilnehmer im Internetforum.

Sinnlos: ist die Weiterführung der Diskussion.

Ich kenne "sinnfrei" im Übrigen nur aus dem obigen Beispiel, während sinnlos eben neben "nutzlos" durchaus auch noch andere verbreitete Bedeutungen hat.

Answer (score 13):

Ein wesentlicher Unterschied ist, dass *sinnlos* sehr viel mehr gebraucht wird als *sinnfrei;* Letzteres steht auch noch nicht lange im Duden. (Meine Ausgabe von 1991 führt das Wort nicht auf.) Auch im [*Deutschen Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm*](http://www.dwb.uni-trier.de/) ist *sinnfrei* nicht erfasst. Hier der Vergleich von [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=sinnlos%2Csinnfrei&year_start=1900&year_end=2011&corpus=8&smoothing=3):

[image: ![](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sinnlos%2Csinnfrei&year_start=1900&year_end=2011&corpus=8&smoothing=3)]

Für mich ist *sinnfrei* eine meist ironisch gemeinte Variante von *sinnlos*. Die Ironie rührt zum Teil daher, dass die Nachsilben *los* und *frei* unterschiedlich verwendet werden.

Bei Wörtern, die auf *frei* enden, ist (fast?) immer die unmittelbare Bedeutung erhalten, d. h., es gibt keine Bedeutungsverschiebung (z. B. *bleifrei, alkoholfrei, keimfrei*). Außerdem werden die Wörter klar als zusammengesetzt empfunden. Als einzige Ausnahme fällt mir im Moment *einwandfrei* ein, was in meinen Ohren mehr wie ein unzusammengesetztes Wort klingt. (Und es weckt andere Assoziationen als *frei von Einwänden*.)

Wörter, die auf *los* enden, haben oft eine übertragene Bedeutung *(bodenlos, farblos, geschmacklos)* oder sind weniger faktisch als *bleifrei* (z. B. *atemlos, schamlos, planlos*). Gegenbeispiele sind z. B. *kostenlos*, *kernlos*.

Comment: bei der metaphorischen Bedeutung würd ich zustimmen - bodenlose Frechheit, farbloser Charakter etc. Aber ironisch versteh ich sinnfrei garnicht, ist dann doch eher eine nüchterne Bewertung imo bei einem z.B. wenig durchdachten Konzept. Ein *suboptimales Konzept* würd ich ironisch verstehen :)

Comment: OK, das scheint also zum Teil Geschmackssache zu sein. [Ich stehe mit meiner Meinung aber nicht ganz alleine.](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article4477406.html)

Comment: ja, die erste Antwort im Link bestätigt dich, die zweite mich imho :) nutzlos/zwecklos - ohne Inhalt/wenig durchdacht imo. Die Herleitung der Ironie aus dem Freiheitsbegriff dort find ich zwar etwas künstlich, aber ist vielleicht ne Generationenfrage von wem der Begriff wie benutzt wurde zu bestimmter Zeit?

Comment: Vielleicht ist es wirklich eine Generationenfrage. Ich glaube, dass _sinnfrei_ vor 20 Jahren noch nicht in meinem Wortschatz war.

Comment: Die Beispiele auf -frei bzw. auf -los deuten für mich auf etwas anderes hin (vielleicht meintest Du das auch so?): bei `-frei` fehlt dem Objekt regelmäßig etwas negativ-abwertendes (Keime, Blei; strittig: Alkohol `;)`), das Ergebnis ist eine aufwertende Qualitätszuschreibung. Bei `-los` fehlt eine positive Qualität (Sinn, Zweck), das Adjektiv ist im Ergebnis eher abwertend. Aber auch hier gibt es Gegenbeispiele: `makellos`, `tadellos` ist eindeutig positiv. Das Ergebnis halte ich auf jeden Fall für zutreffen (unterschiedlicher Sinn der Nachsilben, Ironie).

Comment: @tohu: Das ist ein guter Punkt, den ich eigentlich auch noch hatte erwähnen wollen, aber das hatte ich ganz vergessen.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Dem kann ich voll zustimmen. Es ist immer wieder ein kleiner Gag, Kritik mit Ausdrücken wir "talentfrei" positiv klingen zu lassen.

Comment: Wenn das Empfinden so regelmäßig fehl geht, dann scheint es ein sinnfreies Unterfangen zu sein, die Zusammensetzung von Wörtern mittels diffuser Empfindung bestimmen zu wollen. Das Reden darüber setzt auch keinerlei beachtlichen Erkenntnisprozesse in Gang. Man kann offenbar auch nicht das Empfinden in diese Richtung trainieren.

Answer (score 5):

> Ein Leben ohne Mops ist möglich, aber sinnlos.  (Loriot)

Ich denke, *sinnlos* verwendet man, wenn allgemein Übereinstimmung herrscht, dass etwas per se (aufgrund seiner Natur) keinen tieferen objektiv feststellbaren Sinn haben kann, dass der Zweck/Ziel, wenn überhaupt vorhanden, sehr subjektiv ist. Die Bezeichnung mit *sinnlos* ist dann eher absolut, ein Urteil sozusagen.

*Sinnfrei* würde ich z. B. für ein Konzept/eine Idee nehmen, da diese per se ja einen Zweck und Intention haben (sollten), deswegen entwickelt man sie. Ein schlechtes, kaum durchdachtes Konzept würde man dann als sinnfrei bezeichnen, ein noch schlechteres evtl. auch als noch sinnfreier. Hier ist es mehr eine variable Wertung als ein endgültiges Urteil. Bei *sinnlos* macht der Komparativ meiner Meinung nach nicht viel Sinn (entweder etwas ist lose oder nicht), es hat einen stärkeren absoluten Charakter.

Kurzum: ***sinnfrei*** hat die Bedeutung von ***wenig durchdacht***. So scheint es gemäß [google results](http://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&q=sinnfrei%20AROUND%2810%29%20%22wenig%20durchdacht%22&oq=sinnfrei%20AROUND%2810%29%20%22wenig%20durchdacht%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11809l15159l0l15444l11l9l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0) auch verwendet zu werden. *sinnlos* ist dann schon sozusagen der Superlativ von *sinnfrei*, ohne jeglichen Sinn/Zweck/Nutzen/Intention/Ziel

Comment: Hmm, lustig, für mich ist es eher andersrum, _sinnfrei_ ist eine Steigerung von _sinnlos_. (Ich verstehe Deine Google-Suche mit "AROUND" übrigens nicht, was bedeutet das? Ich weiß auch nicht genau, auf welche der Ergebnisse Du dich da beziehst.)

Comment: @hendrik AROUND(Anzahl Wörter zw. Suchbegriffen) gibt Hits aus, bei denen die Suchbegriffe nicht durch mehr als X Wörter getrennt sind. Recht unbekannter aber imo sehr nützlicher Suchoperator, weil man Begriffe etwas im Kontext suchen kann :) Und in den Ergebnissen steht dann sinnfrei immer dicht an wenig durchdacht, daher meine Conclusio, dass weiter verbreitet. frei von/sein ist für mich relativ wie eben Freiheit, -los heisst für mich aber klar ohne, von daher kanns für mich keine Steigerung von -los geben. wenig durchdacht - zwecklos/sinnlos.Aber scheint in der Tat ambivalente Frage zu sein

Comment: Deine Erklärung zu AROUND war auch meine Vermutung, aber bei den Suchergebnissen (außer dem dritten) habe ich das nicht bestätigt gefunden. Sehe ich andere Ergebnisse als Du?

Comment: evtl. zeigen die Ländereinstellung des Browsers etwas andere Ergebnisse, mehr deutsche als englische Ergebnisse. Ich hab englisch Firefox, bekomm aber um die 900 hits, also Sites bei denen die Suchbegriffe sehr nah beieinander stehen sollten(<10 Wörter), weit mehr als nur einen Treffer seh ich auf der ersten Hits-Seite

Comment: Meine erste Seite [sieht so aus](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3lhsd.png); daher meine Nachfragen.

Comment: hmm, bezweifelst du den Google Operator oder die Vorschau?Es sind 900 hits, bei mir werden standardmässig 100 Hits pro Seite angezeigt (aus der Begutachtung von 10 hits kann man bei google imho wenig schliessen, da google Ranking-Mechanismus unbekannt) über CTRL+F find ich dann mehrere Vorschauausschnitte wo die Begriffe nah beieinander stehen.Alle Seiten einzeln angeschaut hab ich natürlich nicht,nur die erste google Seite mit 100 Hits, da vertrau ich google wie bei ngrams und google trends...imo nur ein Indiz, dass sinnfrei eben wörtlich (kaum durchdacht) und nicht ironisch gebraucht wird

Comment: Ne, ne, ich bin wahllos einigen Links der 1. Seite gefolgt (wie an der Farben im Screenshot zu erkennen ist). Und meist waren _sinnfrei_ und _wenig durchdacht_ recht weit voneinander entfernt.

Comment: @hendrik google ranked nicht primär nach den AROUND operator, der kommt scheinbar nur bei weiteren Suchoperatoren und mehreren Suchbegriffen besonders zum Tragen.Auf den ersten 100 Hits hab ich ca. ein Dutzend Bsp. mit den Begriffen benachbart gefunden. Find ich persönlich repräsentativer als eine einzelene Antwort bei werweisswas. Aber das ist sinnlose Haarspalterei :) bei 7 Millionen google hits zu sinnlos, brauchen wir uns nicht über Nachkommastellen zu streiten...Aber ich versteh nach wie vor nicht, was die ironische (oft gegenteilige) Bedeutung von sinnfrei dann ist, wenn so verwendet?

Answer (score 3):

Die Endung *-los* wird eher verwendet, wenn das Fehlen von etwas grundsätzlich negativ ist (z.B. *wertlos, arbeitslos*). Die Endung *-frei* wird primär verwendet, wenn das Fehlen grundsätzlich positiv ist (z.B. *wertfrei, arbeitsfrei*), daneben aber auch, wenn es nicht bewertet werden soll.

Es scheint einen generellen Trend zur Endung *-frei* an Stelle von *-los* zu geben, der sich aber auf *sinnlos/sinnfrei* nur insofern ausgewirkt zu haben scheint, als es das Wort *sinnfrei* immerhin gibt. Manchmal wird es tatsächlich verwendet, um andere Nuancen auszudrücken. Sinnfreies Spiel ist z.B. nicht sinnlos. Oft wird es aber auch als Synonym für *sinnlos* verwendet - ursprünglich wohl eher scherzhaft und in Analogie zu Wörtern wie *fettfrei*.

Answer (score 1):

[image: google ngram]
[Ein Vergleich der Verwendung zeigt, dass `sinnfrei` kaum gebräuchlich ist](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=sinnfrei,sinnlos&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3), verglichen mit sinnlos.

Was dieses Diagram zeigen soll: Dass 'sinnfrei' kaum benutzt wird, daher sind empirische Erfahrungen, in welchem Kontext man 'sinnfrei' schon gehört hat, mit Vorsicht zu genießen. Man hat es eben überhaupt wohl nur selten gehört/gelesen.

Und da die Frage war, was der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern ist, ist dies auch eine partielle Antwort: In der Häufigkeit der Verwendung gibt es einen erklatanten Unterschied.

Ich will nicht verschweigen, dass ich eigentlich die Diagramfabrik besucht habe, um zu zeigen, dass `sinnfrei` eine junge Neuschöpfung ist, und wenn das Diagram mich widerlegt, dann vielleicht auch andere Besucher.

Comment: I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: Und ist meine Antwort somit sinnlos oder sinnfrei?

Comment: Keines von beiden jetzt wo du es bearbeitet hast ...

Comment: Downvote kam nicht von mir, sinnfrei sind deine Antworten imo hier nie, du denkst dir ja was dabei. Sinnlos/redundant war sie vor dem Edit grösstenteils weil sie nicht klärt, wann man sinnfrei verwendet, was die implizite Frage war und hendrik die gleiche Abb. hatte. Generell ist ngrams ein tolles Tool, aber vielleicht doch eher für Etymologie. Einfache google Suche spuckt 7:1 für sinnlos:sinnfrei aus. Kaum gebräuchlich würd ich das nicht nennen. ngrams listet eben v.a. ältere Bücher, darum bin ich bei Wörtern des täglichen akt. Gebrauchs eher skeptisch...

Comment: Ist vielleicht ein Thema für META inwieweit wir uns hier in den Antworten mit Resultaten versch. Google Dienste bombardieren sollten und wo der Sachverstand der Community per votes entscheidet wie man etwas benutzen sollte. Benutzung von Sprache ist ja nicht festgeschrieben sondern entwickelt sich ständig weiter. Wie sollte man sinnfrei vs. sinnlos verwenden? Das war eigtl. meine Antwort. Im Zweifelsfall votet die Community dann eben die prägnanteste Antwort vom User mit höchsten Rep. wenn mehrere sich uneins sind :)

Comment: Ich hatte einige Zeit an meiner Antwort rumgefummelt, und zwischenzeitlich eine falsche Grafik verklinkt, aber als ich anfing hatte noch niemand sonst eine ngrams-Antwort, und ich habe es eben erst überrascht zur Kenntnis genommen, dass eine zweite dabei ist. Mir scheint, dass kurzfristig die Zeit des Einstellens nur grob angezeigt wird ('10 hours ago', 'yesterday'), und später wird dann auf die Minute genau angezeigt, von wann ein Beitrag ist. Wieso das so ist habe ich noch nicht auf Meta die Zeit gefunden zu recherchieren. Womögl. um gute statt schneller Antworten zu honorieren.

Comment: @user: Gehe einfach mit dem Mauszeiger über die Zeit der Antwort, dann wird der genaue Zeitpunkt der Antwort in einem "tooltip" (wie sagt man das auf Deutsch?) angezeigt. (Deine Antwort wurde kurz vor meiner abgesendet, aber ich habe bestimmt früher angefangen zu tippen `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Oh, Danke für den Tipp! Ich wollte Dich auch nicht kritisieren, sondern mich lediglich von möglichen Plagiatsverdachten entlasten. Kam aber vielleicht eh so an.

Comment: @user: Ja, genau so kams an, aber ich wollte mich auch gerne noch entlasten `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Interpretiert man "frei" hier als "frei von", dann lese ich aus "sinnfrei" eine größere Resistenz gegen den Sinn heraus als aus "sinnlos". Etwas, das sinnlos ist, hat schlicht keinen Sinn, während etwas, das sinnfrei ist, sich entweder vom Sinn befreit hat oder gar nicht dafür anfällig ist.

Comment: Für die Theorie, dass *-frei* ein Nichtvorhandensein stärker als *-los* betont, finde ich kein Beispiel. Das Argument von @HansAdler finde ich etwas überzeugender. Meine Beispielwörter: bleifrei(es Benzin), alkoholfrei(es Bier/Getränk), unfallfrei (Fahrzeug, Fahrer), zu denen es die *-los*-Variante nicht gibt, legen außerdem nahe, dass ein Wortstamm, der auf *l* endet wahrscheinlicher mit *-frei* komplettiert wird.

Answer (score 1):

"sinnfrei" ist eine neue Wortschöpfung.
Aber es passt ganz gut - wie oben schon Einer schrieb - zum sinnfreien (inhaltsleeren) Geschreibsel vieler Chatter...

Answer (score -1):

Sinnfrei = Schwachsinn, oder sogar noch weniger als "schwach", eher völlig frei von Sinn. Evtl. auch als "völligen Schwachsinn" bezeichnend.

Comment: Und im Vergleich dazu 'sinnlos'?